# issues with upgrading of openssl in RedHat 7.2

Tags: redhat, openssl

I'm having problems upgrading in RedHat 7.2

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum install -y $(cat redhat_packages.txt)
```

results:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Package tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package curl-7.35* available.
Package dstat-0.7.2-12.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package iotop-0.6-2.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package swig-2.0.10-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ncurses-devel-5.9-13.20130511.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.5-39.el7_2 for package: python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.0)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.0)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 (updates)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 (installed)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 (updates)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7_0.3
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7_0.4
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7_0.6
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.7.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7_0.7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.4
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.5
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.6
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.8.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.8
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64 (base)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7.9
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.2
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 19 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
curl-7.29.0-25.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with curl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
epel-release-7-7.noarch is a duplicate with epel-release-7-5.noarch
krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 is a duplicate with krb5-libs-1.11.3-49.el7.x86_64
libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
libcurl-7.29.0-25.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcurl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64
libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libffi-3.0.13-11.el7.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.5.3-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcrypt-1.5.3-4.el7.x86_64
libss-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libss-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
libxml2-python-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-python-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with pcre-8.32-12.el7.x86_64
wget-1.14-10.el7_0.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with wget-1.14-10.el7.x86_64
xz-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.x86_64
xz-libs-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-libs-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.x86_64
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with zlib-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
```

When running:

```
$ sudo yum install -y $(cat redhat_packages.txt) --skip-broken
```

Not getting anything much better:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Package tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package curl-7.35* available.
Package dstat-0.7.2-12.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package iotop-0.6-2.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package swig-2.0.10-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ncurses-devel-5.9-13.20130511.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.5-39.el7_2 for package: python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5 will be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-34.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    1:openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 from updates
    1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 from updates
    1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 from updates

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Arch                                     Version                                               Repository                                 Size
================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 python                                          x86_64                                   2.7.5-39.el7_2                                        updates                                    89 k
 python-devel                                    x86_64                                   2.7.5-39.el7_2                                        updates                                   392 k
Updating for dependencies:
 python-libs                                     x86_64                                   2.7.5-39.el7_2                                        updates                                   5.6 M
Skipped (dependency problems):
 openssl                                         x86_64                                   1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7                                   updates                                   712 k
 openssl-devel                                   x86_64                                   1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7                                   updates                                   1.2 M
 openssl-libs                                    x86_64                                   1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7                                   updates                                   953 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade                        2 Packages (+1 Dependent package)
Skipped (dependency problems)  3 Packages

Total download size: 6.1 M
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
(1/3): python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                  |  89 kB  00:00:00
(2/3): python-devel-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                            | 392 kB  00:00:00
(3/3): python-libs-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                             | 5.6 MB  00:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                           7.9 MB/s | 6.1 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
** Found 19 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
curl-7.29.0-25.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with curl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
epel-release-7-7.noarch is a duplicate with epel-release-7-5.noarch
krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 is a duplicate with krb5-libs-1.11.3-49.el7.x86_64
libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
libcurl-7.29.0-25.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcurl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64
libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libffi-3.0.13-11.el7.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.5.3-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcrypt-1.5.3-4.el7.x86_64
libss-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libss-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64
libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
libxml2-python-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-python-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64
pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with pcre-8.32-12.el7.x86_64
wget-1.14-10.el7_0.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with wget-1.14-10.el7.x86_64
xz-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.x86_64
xz-libs-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-libs-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.x86_64
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with zlib-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
  Updating   : python-libs-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                            1/6
  Updating   : python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                                 2/6
  Updating   : python-devel-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                           3/6
  Cleanup    : python-devel-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                             4/6
  Cleanup    : python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   5/6
  Cleanup    : python-libs-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                              6/6
  Verifying  : python-devel-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                           1/6
  Verifying  : python-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                                 2/6
  Verifying  : python-libs-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64                                                                                                                                            3/6
  Verifying  : python-devel-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                             4/6
  Verifying  : python-libs-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                              5/6
  Verifying  : python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   6/6

Updated:
  python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2                                                              python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2

Dependency Updated:
  python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-39.el7_2

Skipped (dependency problems):
  openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7                          openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7                          openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7

Complete!
```

Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have *two* independent openssl installations. One rpm was from RHEL online repository, another rpm was from "anaconda" repository (probably a RHEL installation ISO). I'm not sure how did you manage to install it for the second time, because by default the one openssl should be updated with the new rpm. It's weird you ended up with two installed rpms.

An obvious solution is to `yum remove` all the rpms from anaconda's openssl (for example `yum remove openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64`). But test with your environment first, as usual.

Comment: Thanks. By any chance do you know why I got the openssl from the anaconda repo in the first place?

Comment: Thanks! Package dependency is a real pain... I will try to understand what brought it in...

Comment: Sorry to bring it up again - on a clean redhat 7.2 iso from their website - openssl is already anaconda! So I need to handle it in every system upgrade I do?

Comment: Try to `yum update`  normally - it should be possible. Don't install a second openssl along the old one.