# Openssl error during rpm installation in redhat-7.6

Tags: redhat, openssl

Unable to resolve the error while I am trying to **install kong rpm** from repository.

```
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1
```

Here is the **detailed logs** for the `yum install`

```
#yum localinstall -y "https://kong.bintray.com/kong-community-edition-rpm/centos/7/kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2.el7.noarch.rpm"
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2.el7.noarch.rpm                                                             |  16 MB  00:00:07     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-xo9VHB/kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2.el7.noarch.rpm: kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2-1.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-xo9VHB/kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2.el7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kong-community-edition.noarch 0:1.1.0rc2-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl for package: kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2-1.noarch
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                  | 2.0 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                | 2.0 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms                                                                               | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                         | 2.0 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms                                                                           | 2.0 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms                                                                                   | 2.0 kB  00:00:00     
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Time-HiRes for package: kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: openssl for package: kong-community-edition-1.1.0rc2-1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: make for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) >= 1.3 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) >= 1.10 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-macros for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-libs for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(threads::shared) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(threads) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(constant) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Time::Local) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Storable) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::XHTML) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::Search) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Getopt::Long) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Filter::Util::Call) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Temp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Unix) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Functions) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Path) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Exporter) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Cwd) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Carp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libperl.so()(64bit) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9725-3.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package make.x86_64 1:3.82-23.el7 will be installed
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Exporter.noarch 0:5.68-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-File-Path.noarch 0:2.09-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-File-Temp.noarch 0:0.23.01-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Filter.x86_64 0:1.49-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Usage) >= 1.14 for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Text::ParseWords) for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.40-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.28-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Escapes) >= 1.04 for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Encode) for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Scalar-List-Utils.x86_64 0:1.27-248.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Storable.x86_64 0:2.45-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Time-Local.noarch 0:1.2300-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-constant.noarch 0:1.27-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
---> Package perl-threads.x86_64 0:1.87-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.43-6.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl-Encode.x86_64 0:2.51-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-294.el7_6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Usage.noarch 0:1.63-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Text) >= 3.15 for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Pod-Perldoc for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch 0:3.29-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch 0:3.20-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(parent) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTTP::Tiny) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: groff-base for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-podlators.noarch 0:2.5.1-3.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package groff-base.x86_64 0:1.22.2-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch 0:0.033-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-244.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)

               ...........................

               ...........................

               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-8.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-34.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               ...........................

               ........................... 
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-16.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I found **something relevant here - [issues with upgrading of openssl in RedHat 7.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/806119/issues-with-upgrading-of-openssl-in-redhat-7-2)** and tried to remove the openssl package but struck with a **different error:**

```
# yum remove openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: subscription-manager-rhsm-1.21.10-3.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: wget-1.14-18.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: krb5-libs-1.15.1-37.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: python-libs-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: libssh2-1.4.3-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: coreutils-8.22-23.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: openldap-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
               ...........................

               ...........................
---> Package avahi-libs.x86_64 0:0.6.31-19.el7 will be erased
---> Package cairo.x86_64 0:1.15.12-3.el7 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: cairo(x86-64) >= 1.12.10 for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcairo.so.2()(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package dbus-glib.x86_64 0:0.100-7.el7 will be erased
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.42.4-1.el7 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python for package: pcsc-lite-devel-1.8.8-8.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pcsc-lite-devel.x86_64 0:1.8.8-8.el7 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

Here is the **release info:**

```
# cat /etc/*release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

Any reference would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a packaging error on the part of the third party who provided the package. You should contact them to report the error and to obtain a fixed package.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your openssl version is not compatible with the package that you are installing. Try once by downgrading the package.